# A Query to return records whose average is greater than specified number

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am writing a query which is calculating the average rating of all the reviews. I want to return those records whose average ratings are greater than some number. I went through the mongodb documentation but I couldn't really figure out how to use $gt and $avg together.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5813c1b05c1c450adfd2b09b"),
"reviewerID" : "A1GMWTGXW682GB",
"asin" : "B000068NSX",
"reviewerName" : "MetalFan",
"helpful" : [
    0,
    0
],
"overall" : 4,
"summary" : "Cheap and cool looking, good length",
"unixReviewTime" : 1331856000,
"reviewTime" : "03 16, 2012"
}
```

The record is something similar to this. I want to return those records whose "overall" is greater than say 4.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show some sample documents in your collection and your expected JSON output?

Comment: Does it look okay now? @chridam